# Passing $this->get_field_name() to javascript

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, widgets

### I've tried doing this one of two ways:

1. In the `form` method of my `Widget` class (which extends `WP_Widget`), I have the following snippet, which sets a global javascript variable:

   ```
   if( $instance ) :
   ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           window.widget_order_name = "<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'order' ) ?>";
       </script>
   <?php
   endif;
   ```
2. In the widget admin markup, I also tried to create the following html structure:

   ```
   <div
     field_name='<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'order' ) ?>'
     id='order_field_name'
     class='hidden'>
   </div>
   ```

In my widget admin javascript file, I grab the value of this field_name in one of two ways (as seen below) and then attached that widget name to that of a hidden input field (which contains a value I want to store).

1. The first way, using `window.widget_order_name`:

   ```
   var widget_field_name = window.widget_order_name;
   ```
2. The second way, using `jQuery` to grab  the `field_name`:

   ```
   var widget_field_name = $( '#order_field_name' ).attr( 'field_name' );
   ```

### My problem:

Whenever I first move the widget from the Available Widgets container to my sidebar, I don't get the actual field name, I get instead a sort of *placeholder* for the field name.

So, instead of getting something like this:

```
<input 
  type="hidden" 
  name="widget-hours-widget[2][order][]"
  value="L48">
```

I get this:

```
<input 
  type="hidden" 
  name="widget-hours-widget[__i__][order][]" 
  value="L26">
```

After the save button is clicked, the `field_name` gives me the correct name of the widget, `widget-hours-widget[2]` rather than the placeholder `widget-hours-widget[__i__]`.

Has anybody run into a similar problem or know how to go about fixing it?

Thanks.

Comment: Let's agree that your `__i__` comes from the Widgets class you are overrding, in `function form_callback(...)`, ie.

    `if ( -1 == $widget_args['number'] ) {
        // We echo out a form where 'number' can be set later
        $this->_set('__i__');
        $instance = array();
    }`

Here, `$instance` is set to an empty array. 

In your code, with `$instance` set an empty array, `if( $instance ) :` will be TRUE. Is this what you really want?

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

So I figured out what the problem was. In the statement below, jQuery was grabbing the first element with the id of `#order_field_name`.

```
var widget_field_name = $( '#order_field_name' ).attr( 'field_name' );
```

As it turns out, there were actually *two* elements with that id. The first element with this id is the widget in the *Available Widgets* section. This is the section where you click & drag the widget to a sidebar. This is element the jQuery selector was returning to me.

[image: The widget name and description.]

And the markup:

[image]

### The Solution

I had a click listener that was dynamically adding hidden input boxes with the field name.
So, I used jQuery's tree traversal methods to go back up to widget's `form` element and traverse back down to the element with the `#order_field_name` id. From there, I grabbed the `field_name` attribute, which has the correct `field_name`.

```
$( 'a.add-schedulable' ).click( function( evt ) {

  // ... code omitted ...

  var widget_field_name = $( this ).parents( 'form' ).find( '#order_field_name' ).attr( 'field_name' );

   // ... code omitted ...
});
```

From there, I used a bit of javascript & jQuery to create a hidden input element with the desired attribute, which looks something similar to this:

```
<input 
  type="hidden" 
  name="widget-hours-widget[3][order][]" 
  value="L13">
```